# Strange white area in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a layout in my Android app.

I have found a hidden space above some items that I can't manage. It is not a margin or padding. It is like a rectangular area inside a horizontal layout.

This is the output in the editor:

[image]

What I mean is the upper white space between the top layout border and the other elements, like the left icon, the textview MOV-MP and the rigth icon.

If you need further code or xml, please tell me.

It is a space that cannot be overwritten, I have tried to put the other elements a bit nearer to the top but this white area is not transparent at all.

EDIT

Layout code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearbotones2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_below="@id/linearbotones"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/browser_actions_context_menu_min_padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:id="@+id/zonaVerificadores"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"


                        android:layout_below="@id/type1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView26"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:text="******************  "
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/rvVerificadoresSpot"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type1"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type2"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type3"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type2"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type4"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type3"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type5"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type4"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type6"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type5"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type7"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type6"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/type8"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type7"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        fab:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/zonaFuego"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/fuego"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circle"
                            android:src="@drawable/home_fire_desactivado" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtFuego"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:text="25" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/botonesabajo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@id/dentro"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/btnEditar"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            fab:srcCompat="@drawable/editar" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            fab:srcCompat="@drawable/home_fire_desactivado" />

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/dentroaccion"


                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"


                            android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="false"

                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/checked"
                            app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Desc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivSport"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/Desc"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circle"
                            fab:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/zonaverified"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivVerified"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                fab:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtVerified"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                android:text="@string/Not_verified"
                                android:textColor="@color/red_400"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/zonaVerificadores"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/spot_at"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtUsuariosFuera"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fuera"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtUsuariosDentro"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dentro"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/fuera"


                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"


                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="false"

                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/checked"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/blue_800" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivDirections"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/directions" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDentroFuera"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fixpin"
                        android:text="TextView" />



                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/fixpin"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"

                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        android:src="@drawable/checknegrosincirculo" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dentro"


                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"


                        android:layout_below="@id/txtdistancia"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="false"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtUsuariosFuera"
                        android:src="@drawable/checked"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/green_500" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2

Screenshot after setting a top-margin of -15dp

[image]

Comment: Please share your xml codes.

Comment: @miladsalimi, the complete xml code or only the code for the linearLayout. I ask you because it is a large XML file code.

Comment: please share your layout

Comment: Please share it complete.

Comment: @miladsalimi, done. Thank you

Comment: @miladsalimi, I am not allowed to insert the complete code, it is bigger than the accepted number of characters

Comment: Yes i found this.

Comment: just put the 3 elements in a linearlayout with orientation horizontal and center them vertically from the linear layout by setting         android:gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: @AlanDeep, they are already inside a horizontal linearLayout

Comment: @AlanDeep,with id = Desc

Comment: ok set the gravity to center vertical in linearlayout and remove any padding or margin belonging to these 3 elements

Comment: @AlanDeep, let me chek

Comment: and the linearlayout height should wrap_content

Comment: @AlanDeep, done, thank you, it works

Comment: @AlanDeep, please post your proposal as answer to my question to accept it as right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `LinearLayout` (id=Desc) set the `android:gravity="center"` and let the height `wrap_content`

Also don't forget to remove any padding/margin for the children of this `LinearLayout` (id=Desc)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove these in your `relativeLayout` :

```
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/browser_actions_context_menu_min_padding"
```

Comment: let me check it

Comment: no success, the white area os still there. I have put a top-margin from -15dp to the textView MOV_MAP, and it is now partially hidden behind this area. Screenshot added in the question

Comment: @mvasco Ok check it and if you want to remove space in bottom remove this `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"`

Comment: Done, but the white area is still there

Comment: Your `relativeLayout` is a child of something else component , i should see them.